# Conditional rendering of the bounded taskflow (jsff based)

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have page with three columns,details of each of the columns are as follows(in the attached image)

![Image showing column desc for the jspx page[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ZXI.png)
The use case is :I want to display one of the jsff's in the second &one in the  third column based upon the tree node selected.
The approach i used is to generate a contextual event on tree node click with payload and a subscriber for the same for second and third column ,Now while trying to use the router to render the content conditionally,i'm failing .
The router gets invoked only for the time page loads and second time the control does not even go the router ,can anyone tell me what is that I'm missing here to achieve the use case.

Jdev version :11.1.1.7.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Contextual events are done in the view so once the event hit the taskflow, your router will already been evaluated and your contextual event gets passed on to the current view. 
It doesn't make the TF to initialize again.

Something you could do, it when the events triggers inside the TF view, you need to fire an action which points to the router.

So in your event handler you just navigate to your router. 
Have a look at this one for navigation: https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how-to_navigate_in_bounded_task_flows

Answer (score 1):

If you tree is in the parent jspx page you don't really need contextual events to manipulate taskflows. Just pass required data as taskflow's parameter and set `Refresh` property to `IfNeeded` for your taskflow binding to rerun your taskflow when its parameters changed.

If your tree also resides in taskflow and its sibling taskflow for details view then you indeed need contextual event, that should be catched at the parent jspx page (or taskflow) and then follow approach I've described earler with only change that parameter will come not from tree directly, but from payload of event.